# WCF url rewriting for net.tcp binding

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, url-rewriting, net.tcp

I'm trying to rewrite URL (with IIS) for WFC service which uses net.tcp binding. I have WFC service which is hosted on first machine and all works fine - I can use it without any problems. 
Now I have second IIS host where I'd created application which contains only web.config (it should rewrite it's address to first machine's WCF) and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="service/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="net.tcp://192.168.1.60/service/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Input URL that should be rewritten is something like:

> net.tcp//localhost/service/SampleService.svc

When I check logs of rewriting everything look fine but when I use address of this application to connect (which should rewrite url to WFC) I receive only errors that there is no WCF endpoint. I tried many combinations of URL rewrite rule but all in vain. Both ISS applications enables protocols: http, net.tcp, net.pipe, ARR enables proxy as well.

I didn't find any threads about redirecting net.tcp WCF's however I get some hints from [URL Rewriting WCF services](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/17a1c294-645f-4bca-ae48-65b668374b81/url-rewriting-wcf-services-and-wsdl?forum=wcf) but it's all about http bindings.
I'm not sure if it is doable to rewrite my service url with IIS so if there is any other approach I'm looking forward for any suggestions.

Comment: I dont think that applies to cross bindings. you can have one more endpoint with http binding...why are you doing url rewrite?

Comment: I need to rewrite it to hide real address of WCF services, also I can't host them on second machine because its performance is too low (I would use http if that performance would not be important but in my case connection efficiency is crucial)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible...you have to rewrite URL in same site and same application pool.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2011/08/25/return-404-4-not-found-when-url-rewrite.aspx

Comment: at the bottom of that website you can see solution, that's why I did write that ARR enables proxy already

Comment: Ahh,, i did not see that

Comment: then I think the problem is in URL...if you observe in the link you mentioned in question, URL is relative and not absolute

Comment: which server request should route to should be handled by ARR

Comment: so since my WCF path is: //192.168.1.60/service/ and web.config of second application is at: //192.168.1.101/service/ then how should rule look like?

Comment: I dont know how to work with ARR...you need to find out how to setup routing in ARR...